# How to refer to nameless folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i want to change the icon of a nameless folder using the .bat file :

```
@echo off
set /p "fld=Folder: "
set /p "ico=Icon file: "
md "%fld%\icons" 2>nul
if exist %ico% copy "%ico%" "%fld%\icons\icon.ico" /y 1>nul
attrib -h -s "%fld%\desktop.ini" 2>nul
(
echo/[.ShellClassInfo]
echo/IconResource=icons\icon.ico,0
) > "%fld%\Desktop.ini"
attrib +h +s -a "%fld%\Desktop.ini"
attrib +r "%fld%"
attrib +h "%fld%\icons"
taskkill -im explorer.exe /f >nul&start explorer
pause
```

but i cannot refer to the nameless file that only contains a blank space (created by pressing Alt + 255 while renaming) ! when i use blank space instead of %fld% and run bat file! i want to change the .bat and remove %fld% with the reference to my nameless folder !

i get output :

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Path not found - C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\if
The system cannot find the path specified.
Path not found - C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\if
Path not found - C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\if
```

Comment: You have to type `ALT+255` when you enter the folder name at your prompt.

Comment: Output :
File not found - ALT+255\desktop.ini

and it creates an new folder with name 'ALT+255' and the icon i gave !

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean literally type it...rather, press and hold `ALT` while typing `255`. Just like you did when renaming the folder.

Comment: OK but is there any way to do that through bat file ? i mean from the script ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to prompt for it, you want it to be hard-coded in the batch file?

Comment: yes ! u r absolutely correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
set /p "fld=Folder: "
```

to

```
set "fld= "
```

The character after the `=` that looks like a space is actually `ALT+255` (press and hold `ALT` and type 255 on the keypad.

### EDIT

Ah, it's been awhile since I've needed something like this.

You also have to change the code page.

1. Make the first line blank (this is necessary, because there are hidden chars in the first line for UTF-8 text file).
2. Put `CHCP 65001` as second line.
3. Insert the rest of your batch code.
4. Save the BAT file as UTF-8.

[Thanks to this answer for jogging my memory.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854500/2441)

Comment: Have tried that ! but the output is ! it creates a folder with this character - á ! :(

Comment: Try changing your console font to "Lucida Console". EDIT: it still doesn't like ALT255

Comment: Now the character is '�' ! but i dont know how to save Save the BAT file as UTF-8 ?

Comment: Open notepad, 'save as' then under encoding Select "UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

just alt+0255 can be passed in batch
example

### a.bat

a="ÿ"
echo "ÿ"
set /p c="gg"

in here ÿ will be viewd as emptysace in batch when running ignore set /p c="gg" that just for making batch wait wait untill u press any value